# Excel keeps saying it repaired my file, but nothing's wrong

Tags: microsoft-excel, file-corruption, microsoft-excel-365

Every time I open one of my Excel files it shows a sidebar to the left saying it has recreated it ("Återskapa dokument" in Swedish) and says I should save the one I want.

The file is opened and I can't see anything wrong with it. I've tried all menu entries for the file icon inside the "recreate" sidebar, I tried editing and then save, I tried close for the entire sidebar. When I save the file, the sidebar does disappear and if I then close the file and reopen it without closing Excel inbetween, the sidebar does not reappear. But if I then close Excel and restart it, then the sidebar appears again when I open the file.

But whatever I do, the next time I open the file, Excel again opens that same sidebar and says it has been recreated...

This seems to happen from time to time (not just with this Excel file), and I often find that sidebar to be "sticky", i.e. I don't know what sequence of operations will make it stop showing up. I usually get rid of it eventually, but I never really understand what action(s) it was that made it go away and stay away.

I've failed to find docs about this using Google and the help section available from within the sidebar doesn't seem to address this and the description there doesn't quite match the actual behavior I observe. Perhaps i misunderstand what this sidebar is actually called in English so my English search attempts are off the mark?

I'd be very grateful to be pointed to appropriate docs and/or an explanation of how to get rid of this nagging sidebar properly every time it occurs.

I assume a workaround would be to copy the file's contents to a new workbook, but I'd really like to know how to resolve the issue without resorting to that.

Comment: I think I got rid of it now. I opened Excel, opened ANOTHER file, got the sidebar, opened the "faulty" file from the sidebar, Saved it, closed it, then closed Excel without saving the other file. My best guess is that Excel doesn't detect that it's the fault file that I open when I open it from the start screen. It must probably be opened from the file's icon in the "Recreated..." sidebar. I'll try to keep it in mind for the next time, to see if it works again. Seems like a bug in that case.

Comment: ^^^^ If that is the resolution of your question, you should post it as an answer

Comment: I believe it is designed behavior, MS wants you to perform an action to make that recovery option go away. I think the options given are not intuitive, as sometimes I may encounter that screen a couple of times until I handle it "correctly". Anyway, you can manually go to these recovery options... look at this link: https://trumpexcel.com/recover-unsaved-excel-files/

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Yes. But I think I (or someone else) should confirm it first, because frankly, I'm not sure that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing a couple of times, it seems that the sidebar will go away only if you open the faulty file FROM THE SIDEBAR. If you open Excel by clicking the fauly file, or open it from Excel's start screen, then it won't help whatever you do. The sidebar will reappear next time you open Excel. In other words, to get rid of the sidebar:

1. Start Excel.
2. Open ANOTHER file. The sidebar will appear.
3. Using the icon in the sidebar, open the faulty file.
4. Save it. The sidebar will disappear.
5. That's it really. To verify:
6. Close Excel.
7. Start Excel.
8. Open the previously faulty file. The sidebar shouldn't appear now.